# Functions (funciones)

Tags: javascript, java, visual-studio, funciones, function

Hola tengo que hacer un ejercicio de funciones que intenté hacerlo de mil maneras y me sigue tirando error. Les cuento la consigna: "Escribí una función longitudNombreCompleto que tome un nombre y un apellido como parámetro y devuelva su longitud total, contando un espacio extra para separar a ambos."
Lo que yo hice fue

código

```
function longitudNombreCompleto('Cosme', 'Fulanito') {
    return longitudNombreCompleto.length 
}
```

y ya no se de qué manera abordarlo por que incluso esta última resolución me tira error, o sea está mal. Agradecería la ayuda muchísimo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! como contas cuanto mide un string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la estructura de la función está mal elaborada, ¿al parecer son tus primeros pasos en Javascript eh? te recomiendo la lectura de esté artículo que trata el tema de la creación de funciones: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

En el caso a tu pregunta, tu función quedaría así más menos:

```javascript
function longitud (nombre, apellido) {
  return (nombre + apellido).length;
}
```

¿Qué hice básicamente? tomo los 2 parámetros introducidos a la función, los concateno (juntarlos) y retorno el tamaño de ellos.

Ya que tenemos la función elaborada, podemos usarla de la siguiente manera, en este caso le introduzco los strings "Juan" y "Alfonso":

```javascript
var tamaño = longitud("Juan", "Alfonso");
console.log( tamaño );
// mostrará el número 11
```

Profundiza y repasa más sobre el tema para que puedas realizar los ejercicios correctamente. Comenta si lo lograstes. Saludos!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Sí, de hecho estoy haciendo un curso de programación, y es mi primera vez aprendiendo todo esto. Mil gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Como dice Rodny, tu función esta mal elaborada.

Lo explicó muy bien. Una pequeña corrección en el código para que te cuente con el espacio extra para separar los nombres:

```js
function longitudNombreCompleto(nombre, apellido) {
    return (nombre + ' ' + apellido).length; 
}

console.log(longitudNombreCompleto('Cosme', 'Fulanito'))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, realmente me ayuda un montón <3